# What are Implications of Commutative Diagrams?

Tags: optimization, iterative-method, discretization

This question may be too broad. But I really want to know some concrete explanations.  I often find various commutations appear here and there, which concerns the application order of two operators.  For examples, between exterior calculus of the differential forms and discretization,  optimization-then-discretization or discretization-then-optimization, and inner-outer iterations.  Do you have some understanding of concrete examples where the commutation plays an important role?

Comment: It's important what part of the expression is continuous. This as a hint.

Comment: Could you refine your question? I cannot connect the dots from commutative operators to what you say about differential forms.